# How to grant access to a non privileged user to run conda in node docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running a container from this dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14


RUN apt update && apt upgrade
RUN apt install -y wget build-essential libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev zlib1g-dev
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.4/Python-3.9.4.tgz
RUN tar xzf Python-3.9.4.tgz
RUN cd Python-3.9.4 \
    && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
    && make install

RUN alias python=python3

RUN wget https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
RUN bash Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh -b
RUN ln -s /root/mambaforge/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda

RUN conda init
RUN conda create -n myenv nodejs=14 r=4 r-import r-dplyr r-tidyr

# USER node
```

With the above code, I have access to conda in the shell. But if I uncomment the last line, I get:

```
conda: Permission denied
```

I have tried:

```
chmod -R a+rwx /usr/bin/conda
```

and

```
RUN chown -R node:node /usr/bin/conda
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/conda
```

I found on the internet, none of which worked. What should I do to give the node user the required permission?

Comment: Are you running the chown/chmod commands BEFORE changing user to node, and THEN running conda init as "node"?

Comment: @clarj Yes, exactly.

Comment: Why are you doing this in a `FROM node` image; can you start from an image that has Conda preinstalled, or at least `python`?  Can you use a lighter-weight Python package environment like Pipenv or plain `pip`?

Comment: I would agree, unless you are somehow planning on expanding with a node application in the same container, you would likely be better starting with a [Conda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3) image or a [python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) image.